# Merging multiple localized left key paths in the same NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate?

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate, appkit, nspredicateeditor, nspredicateeditorrow

I'm attempting to replicate the Finder's NSPredicateEditor-based metadata search in an app.

[I'd prefer to get the Finder's exact NSPredicateEditor for free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311255/using-nspredicateeditor-is-there-a-way-to-get-all-of-the-finder-search-categori), but unless anyone has a better answer for that question it looks like I'm going to have to replicate Finder's search as best as I can.

When working on mirroring the `Kind` option, I'm hitting a problem. I start by saving a Finder Spotlight search with all available `Kind` options.

[image: Every <code>Kind</code> option in Finder search.]

When I `Get Info` on the resulting saved search folder, the Query is listed as:

```
(kMDItemContentTypeTree=com.apple.application) && 
(kMDItemContentTypeTree=public.archive) && 
(kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.content) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 8) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 9) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 13) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 7) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 10) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 11) && 
(_kMDItemGroupId = 12) && 
(kMDItemContentTypeTree = public.text) && 
(kMDItemKind = "my_Kind_custom_text*"cdw)
```

The problem I'm seeing is that the single "Kind" user-displayed text contains multiple key paths that are used in the resulting NSPredicate based on whichever right value is picked.

"Kind" can represent (at least) `kMDItemContentTypeTree`, `_kMDItemGroupId`, or `kMDItemKind`.

When I create an [NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nspredicateeditorrowtemplate), I pass an array of Left Expressions, Operators, and Right Expressions. The row template is then created containing **all possible permutations** of Left/Operator/Right.

(Note: I'm creating all `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`s [programatically rather than in Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4709218/1265393)).

Finder is **not** creating all possible permutations of the 3 Left key paths and 12 Right values. It is selectively assigning a certain left key path based on the value picked on the right.

I am localizing the row templates using `NSRuleEditor`'s `formattingDictionary` property, based on the guide found here: http://funwithobjc.tumblr.com/post/1482915398/localizing-nspredicateeditor

I **can** assign the same localization of "Kind" to two different key path expressions in two different `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`s.

When I have two row templates localized to "Kind" using the **same** left key path expression, the following "merge the templates" quote is true and only one "Kind" shows up in the list. The right popup is a union set of all of the vaules from the two templates.

[image: two row templates, single key path, same localization]

> At runtime, NSPredicateEditor will merge the templates together, and the second popup will show a union of all the operators of your date templates. http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/282859-nspredicateeditorrowtemplate-and-dynamic-templateviews.html

However, when I create two row templates, both localized to "Kind", using **different** left key path expressions, I instead get two "Kind" rows in my left expression popup. The templates are not merged.

[image: two row templates, two key paths, same localization]

How should I replicate Finder's behavior? I need to somehow merge the left key paths if they have the same localization *even if they represent different key paths / expressions*, resulting in a single row template with multiple left key paths each with independent sets of right values.

Comment: I'll dig around a bit, but my gut is telling me you're going to need a custom `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate` subclass.

Comment: The Finder uses `NSRuleEditor`.

Comment: If all keypaths are the same, is it possible to put the Any popup and the text field in mergeable row templates?

Comment: @Willeke if the key paths are the same the rows are merged as in my `Name | Kind` screenshot (if that's what you mean).

Comment: Are they merged if the first kind has two popup buttons like "Image" and the second kind has a text field like "Other"?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to have a single source property, then multiple renamed getters that return that property.

Each `kindImage`-type getter is a key path that can be targeted independently in the predicate editor.

```
@objc lazy var kind: String = { return getKind() }()
@objc lazy var kindImage      = kind
@objc lazy var kindText       = kind
@objc lazy var kindDocument   = kind
```

Despite returning the same value, the predicate editor rows will not merge because they are using different key paths.